# Снятие выделения QTreeView при клике на пустую область

Tags: c++, qt

Собственно, вопрос в сабже. Требуется при клике на пустую область `QTreeView` убрать выделение с пунктов дерева. Как программно снять выделение, я нашёл. Подскажите, как отловить событие клика по пустом пространству?

Comment: проверить что под координатой курсора нет элемента

Comment: По-моему, костылём попахивает.

Comment: ну, поищите тогда такое свойство у Q*View (насколько я помню, таких нет)

Comment: В то-то и дело, таких свойств не знаю. Потому и пришёл помощи просить.

Comment: сейчас скину пример "костыля" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть в том, что мы подключаем наш `QTreeView` к фильтру нашего окна и в обработчике событий от подключенных к фильтру виджетов ищем "наш" `QTreeView` и ожидаем события отпуска кнопки мышки.

После по позиции курсора определяем находился ли под ним элемент `QTreeView` и если нет – очищаем выделение.

Чтобы код был минималистичным, перенес в объявление методов их определение.

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
            model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));
            model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));
            model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));
            model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));
            model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));

            view.setModel(&model);

            // Добавление view.viewport() к фильтру данного класса
            view.viewport()->installEventFilter(this);

            setCentralWidget(&view);
        }

    public:
        QTreeView view;
        QStandardItemModel model;

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) {
            if (watched == view.viewport() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
                QMouseEvent *me = static_cast <QMouseEvent *> (event);

                QModelIndex index = view.indexAt(me->pos());
                qDebug() << index << index.isValid() << me->pos();

                if (!index.isValid()) {
                    view.clearSelection();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
        }
};
```